# How to force result of CGI's self_url to use & instead of ;?

Tags: perl, cgi

It now output such kind of stuff:

```
?name=fred;age=24;favorite_color=3
```

How can I instruction it to output `?name=fred&age=24&favorite_color=3` instead?

Comment: @Quentin,Seems not recognized as the same by `URI` module.

Comment: They are distinct URIs, but once the query string is parsed, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-oldstyle_urls` parameter of [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI):

```
use CGI qw(:standard -oldstyle_urls);
warn self_url();    # http://localhost?one=uno&two=duo
```